# Input an array of unknown size in java

Tags: java, arraylist, input

How do I input an array whose length may vary? The input is space delimited and ends when I press enter

```
public class ArrayInput {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(){//what condition to use here?
            al.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

An example would be:

```
1 2 5 9 7 4  //press enter here to mark end of input
```

Comment: Are all you integers in the same line ? If so, just read a line from the `Scanner`.

Comment: you can refer to http://www.big4future.com/2015/09/fast-io-with-java-good-for-online.html it has various method for string,integer,etc

Answer (score 4):

Since all your input is in a single line, you can read the entire line and then split it to integers :

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
int[] numbers = new int[tokens.length];
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
```

Comment: `"\\s+"` instead of `" "` ?

Answer (score 2):

Read the entire line using `sc.nextLine()` and then `split()` using `\\s+`. This way, you don't have to worry about size of input (number of elements). Use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse Strings as integers.